# Accessing date field from foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to use a generic date view on a model which has a foreign key to another model where the date is stored. My view class looks like this.

```
class MileageYearView(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Miles.objects.all()
    date_field = 'ride__date'
    make_object_list = True
```

here is what my models look like

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(RideProfile)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date of ride')
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Miles(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    actual_miles = models.FloatField('actual miles')
```

And the error I'm encounterint is `Miles has no field named 'ride__date'`

I'm new to this, and in terms I can understand I am trying to join the two models so I can view all the mile entries for one year.

Comment: +1 for a question that's causing me to pull the Django source.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to achieve this that I've found is to create a @property in class Miles that returns the ride date, as follow:

```
@property
def ride_date( self ):
    return self.ride.date
```

and use 'ride_date' as the value for date_field in class MileageYearView

Hope it helps!